# How to create your own library for Android development to be used in every program you write?

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

I am a Delphi programmer and have written, over the years, hundreds of classes and routines which I can use in every Delphi program I write.

This **library** is called dlib and can be **used in every Delphi program** by putting this folder in my library path and using one of the units in the uses section of a Delphi unit.

Being completely new to Java and Android development, I am wondering how to do this in similar way.

**So my question, how can I write own classes, put them in some global folder, and use these classes and routines in every Android program I write** ?

I know this is a basic question, which I can probably find out by searching Google and trying it out in Eclipse, but if someone can put me on the right track, I know I will save much time.

Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly caution against making these kind of general libraries. Java tends to have most of the functionality you need already, and more often than not, smarter people have done whatever you need doing already. What kind of things do your general libraries do?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You have to create Android Library Project.
Create android project in Eclipse, enter Project Properties -> Android and check isLibrary property. Now you can add this library to your Android Application project by adding it to list on the same property page.

More detailed instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) in Working with Library Projects section

Comment: If two different apps both use the same android library project, are two copies of the same library installed when both apps are installed on the same phone?

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist The library is actually pulled in at compile time. So yes, both apps have their own copies of the library bundled with them

Comment: There has got to be a better way. Perhaps in a future version of Android.

Answer (score 11):

[Instructions for creating a library in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html):

> ### Create a library module
>
> To create a new library module in your project, proceed as follows:
>
> 1. Click **File > New > New Module**.
> 2. In the **Create New Module** window that appears, click Android Library, then click Next.
>
>    There's also an option to create a **Java Library**, which builds a traditional JAR file. While a JAR file is useful for many
>      projects—especially when you want to share code with other
>      platforms—it does not allow you to include Android resources or
>      manifest files, which is very useful for code reuse in Android
>      projects. So this guide focuses on creating Android libraries.
> 3. Give your library a name and select a minimum SDK version for the code in the library, then click **Finish**.
>
> Once the Gradle project sync completes, the library module appears in
>   the **Project** panel on the left. If you don't see the new module
>   folder, make sure it's displaying the [Android
>   view](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#ProjectFiles).
>
> ### Convert an app module to a library module
>
> If you have an existing app module with all the code you want to
>   reuse, you can turn it into a library module as follows:
>
> 1. Open the module-level `build.gradle` file.
> 2. Delete the line for the `applicationId`. Only an Android app module can define this.
> 3. At the top of the file, you should see the following:
>      
>      `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
>      
>      Change it to the following:
>      
>      `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
>      
>      Save the file and click **Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle
>      Files**.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer, this is so much better with Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

If your library is in .java files composed of java code. There's a really detailed tutorial of how to use the library at mobile.tutsplus.com. Link below:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-creating-android-compliant-libraries/

For Example I wanted to use the Pull To Refresh library by Chrisbanes at Github.com here https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/tree/master/library. The library's structure is in the form of an Android app. It has the form like below:

```
res/
src/
AndroidManifest.xml
pom.xml
project.properties
```

**How to use on Eclipse:**

1. Create new project in Eclipse. Give a name to your project. Select
   "Create project from existing source". Select the location of the
   root folder containing the above mentioned files in "Location".
   Select your target and click finish.
2. Select properties of the newly project you created. Select "Android"
   option. Select the "Is Library" checkbox if it's not already
   selected. close properties.
3. Add a reference to the library from the project that is going to use
   this library. Select your project that uses this library. Open
   Properties. Select "Android" option. At the bottom on the "Is
   Library". Don't select checkbox of "Is Library". Click "Add" button
   on the right. Your project that you created on step 1 and 2 should
   be listed ready for selection. select it and click apply. close
   properties.
4. You're ready to reference the classes from your project.

Comment: thanks it help me... regards from our fgroupindonesia team :D

Answer (score 4):

With java, you create a Java Archive (jar) that contains all your classes (*.class files) of that library and the jar file *is* your library.

To use it, simply add it to the *classpath*.

(For "jar" and "classpath": basic Java concepts, please use google to find tutorials, you'll have to understand those concepts anyway, the sooner, the better ;) )

Comment: Hi, can I have drawables or layouts in my jar libraray?

Comment: afaik, the answer is: no. Use the android library concept as described in the accepted answer for drawables and layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all of your class in Java and make a jar file. Use this jar in your android project by copying in libs/ folder and then adding in to build path. Make a clean of project and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using new android studio version and gradle 7.0.3

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 2
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

## Creating module

1. Create new project with empty activity
2. Click file -> new -> new module -> and choose android library.
3. After new module created you can add java class or something for
   your library

## Export library to AAR file

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267339/export-android-library-as-aar-file/50267507) for more information

## Export library to jitpack.io

Set this file like this

**build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (module:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (module: YourLibraryName)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'com.github.YourGithubUsername'
                from components.release
                artifact androidSourcesJar // optional sources
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Create file jitpack.yml in root project (YourProjectName -> Gradle -> right click -> new -> file -> name it "jitpack.yml" and put this code to jitpack.yml file

```
jdk:
  - openjdk11
before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew
install:
#  - ./gradlew build :lib:publishToMavenLocal
  - ./gradlew build publishToMavenLocal
```

[Share your project to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github)

Visit [jitpack](https://jitpack.io) website

Follow [this](https://medium.com/@ome450901/publish-an-android-library-by-jitpack-a0342684cbd0) step for upload your library