# How to create a common code base in Android Studio Project

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, common-code

I have several eclipse projects which are almost same type. How can i import these to Android Studio and make a common code base in Android Studio.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: thanks. but actually i need a common code base procedure in Android Studio.

Comment: what do you mean with "common code base"? Like a library?

Comment: i heard about it. I have several projects (more than 20) with almost 90% same codes and resources. So, if i have a common code base, then i do not have to write 90% code for all apps.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085313/how-to-create-your-own-library-for-android-development-to-be-used-in-every-progr