# How can I create an Android library

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am trying to create an Android library for my friend. Something like

[floating action github](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

As you see, there is the `"compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'"`

How can I create a wrapper/client like this for others to use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). this question might be to broad for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create your own library for Android development to be used in every program you write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085313/how-to-create-your-own-library-for-android-development-to-be-used-in-every-progr)

Answer (score 0):

Your question already has an answer. These two questions should help you

- [How to create your own library for Android development to be used in every program you write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085313/how-to-create-your-own-library-for-android-development-to-be-used-in-every-progr)
- [How to create my own android library and host it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741309/how-to-create-my-own-android-library-and-host-it)

First one explains how you can create an android library project and second one explains how you can host it so that anybody can use it.